# Updating RecyclerView in a Fragment - Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a 3 fragments on my view pager. On my 3rd fragment is a recyclerViewer which contains contact list. Now, i am finding it difficult as to how to update my contact list (recycleViewer with data) from my database. `recycleview` in Fragment.axml is inflated from Fragment 3.cs.

**Fragment 3.cs**

```
    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
            {

                RecyclerView recyclerView = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Fragment3, container, false) as RecyclerView;
                implementRecyclerView(recyclerView);

                return recyclerView;
            }

private void SetUpRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView)
        {        

            recyclerView.SetLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(recyclerView.Context));

        recyclerView.SetAdapter(Adapter);

            recyclerView.Click += eventClicked;

            Adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();

            recyclerView.SetItemClickListener((rv, position, view) =>
            {
                //An item has been clicked
                Context context = view.Context;
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, typeof(EventDetailActivity));

                context.StartActivity(intent);
            });

        }
```

This is where my `RecycleView` that actually displays the contact list after being inflated in the `Fragment 3.cs`

**Fragment 3 axml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

//id of RecycleView 
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

In this activity, I add some data to my database. After adding, i call the `RefreshListWithNewData()` to update my RecyclerView (contact list). I keep getting `NullReference` trying to get the id of the RecycleView. 
**SomeActivity.cs**

```
JavaList<Contact> myContactList = new JavaList<Contact>();


private async void AddNewGames(){

//add contacts to database 

await RefreshListWithNewData()


}


private async Task RefreshListWithNewData(){

                foreach(var item in items){
                Contact people = new Contact();
                people.Name = item.Object.Name;
                myContactList.Add(people);



}

 //trying to update recycleview in Fragment 3.cs
refreshRecycler = (RecyclerView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.recycleview)
adapter = new ContactAdapter(myContactList);
 refreshRecycler.SetAdapter(adapter);
```

**My question is why can't i reach that RecycleView even after i have given it an id called `recycleview`?**

**Updated Fragment3.cs**

```
public class Fragment3 : SupportFragment



{
    public RecyclerView refresh;




    public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);


    }



    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {


        RecyclerView recyclerView = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Fragment3, container, false) as RecyclerView;


        SetUpRecyclerView(recyclerView);




        return recyclerView;



    }




    private void SetUpRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView)
    {

        //var value= GetRandomSubList(PeaceEventsCollection.GetPeaceEvents(), 5);
        var value = PeaceEventsCollection.GetPeaceEvents();

        recyclerView.SetLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(recyclerView.Context));





        var Adapter = new EventAdapter(PeaceEventsCollection.GetPeaceEvents());






    recyclerView.SetAdapter(Adapter);

        recyclerView.Click += eventClicked;

        Adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();

        recyclerView.SetItemClickListener((rv, position, view) =>
        {
            //An item has been clicked
            Context context = view.Context;
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, typeof(EventDetailActivity));
            intent.PutExtra(EventDetailActivity.EXTRA_NAME,  value[position].EName);
            intent.PutExtra(EventDetailActivity.EXTRA_DETAIL, value[position].EDescritption);
            intent.PutExtra(EventDetailActivity.EXTRA_DATE, value[position].EDate);



            //perform activity to event page
            context.StartActivity(intent);
        });



    }


    private JavaList<PeaceEvents> GetRandomSubList(JavaList<PeaceEvents> items, int amount)
    {
        JavaList<PeaceEvents> list = new JavaList<PeaceEvents>();
        Random random = new Random();
        while (list.Count < amount)
        {
            list.Add(items[random.Next(items.Count)]);
        }

        return list;
    }

    private void eventClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Intent showEvent = new Intent(Context, typeof(EventActivity));
        this.StartActivity(showEvent);
    }

    public class EventAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter
    {

        private JavaList<PeaceEvents> peaceEvents;

        public EventAdapter(JavaList<PeaceEvents> peaceEvents)
        {
            this.peaceEvents = peaceEvents;


        }


        public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
        {

            EventHolder hold = holder as EventHolder;
            hold.EventName.Text = peaceEvents[position].EName;
            hold.EventImg.SetImageResource(peaceEvents[position].EImage);
            hold.EventDate.Text = peaceEvents[position].EDate;
            hold.EventVenue.Text = peaceEvents[position].EVenue;
            hold.EventDescription.Text = peaceEvents[position].EDescritption;

        }


        public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
        {
            View v = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.List_Event, parent, false);
            EventHolder holder = new EventHolder(v);

            return holder;
        }

        public override int ItemCount
        {

            get { return peaceEvents.Size(); }

        }


    }

}




public class EventHolder : RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{

    public TextView EventName;
    public ImageView EventImg;
    public TextView EventDate;
    public TextView EventVenue;
    public TextView EventDescription;
    public TextView textIcon;
    public TextView EventDetailDescription;


    public EventHolder(View itemView) : base(itemView)
    {
        EventName = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textViewEvent);
        EventImg = itemView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView);
        EventDate = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textViewDate);
        EventVenue = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textViewVenue);
        EventDescription = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textViewDescription);






    }

}
```

**EventActivity**

```
 public class EventActivity : AppCompatActivity


    {

        private EditText EventName;
        private EditText EventDateTime;
        private EditText EventVenue;
        private EditText EventDescription;
        private ProgressBar circular_progress;
        private Button saveData;
        private LinearLayout list_view;
        private RecyclerView recycle;
        // private EventAdapter adapter;
        JavaList<PeaceEvents> peace_Events = new JavaList<PeaceEvents>();


        //  private PeaceEvents selectedEvents;

        private const string FirebaseUrl = "";





        private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;



        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Events);
            // Create your application here
            SupportToolbar toolBar = FindViewById<SupportToolbar>(Resource.Id.toolBar);

            SetSupportActionBar(toolBar);

            //view 

            circular_progress = FindViewById<ProgressBar>(Resource.Id.circularProgress);
            EventName = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.eventName);
            EventDateTime = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtDateAndTime);
            EventVenue = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.venue);
            EventDescription = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtDescribe);
            list_view = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.list_view);

            saveData = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnLogin);


            saveData.Click += saveEventData;









            SupportActionBar ab = SupportActionBar;
            ab.SetHomeAsUpIndicator(Resource.Drawable.ic_menu);
            ab.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

            mDrawerLayout = FindViewById<DrawerLayout>(Resource.Id.drawer_layout);

            NavigationView navigationView = FindViewById<NavigationView>(Resource.Id.nav_view);
            if (navigationView != null)
            {
                SetUpDrawerContent(navigationView);
            }

        }

        private void saveEventData(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CreateEvent();
        }

        private async void CreateEvent()
        {
            PeaceEvents events = new PeaceEvents();
            events.EName = EventName.Text;
            events.EDate = EventDateTime.Text;
            events.EVenue = EventVenue.Text;
            events.EDescritption = EventDescription.Text;

            var firebase = new FirebaseClient(FirebaseUrl);

            //add item 

            var item = await firebase.Child("").PostAsync<PeaceEvents>(events);

            await LoadData();


        }

        private  async Task LoadData()
        {
            circular_progress.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;

            var firebase = new FirebaseClient(FirebaseUrl);
            var items = await firebase.Child("").OnceAsync<PeaceEvents>();

            peace_Events.Clear();

            EventAdapter adpater;




            foreach(var item in items){
                PeaceEvents events = new PeaceEvents();
                events.EName = item.Object.EName;
                events.EDate = item.Object.EDate;
                events.EDescritption = item.Object.EDescritption;
                events.EVenue = item.Object.EVenue;
                events.EImage = item.Object.EImage;

                peace_Events.Add(events);




            }

           // Fragment3.UpdateContactList<Ja>(peace_Events);

            //adpater = new EventAdapter(peace_Events);
            ////recycle.SetAdapter(adpater);
            ////recycle.SetLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
            //adpater.NotifyDataSetChanged();


            //recycle.SetAdapter(adpater);






            circular_progress.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;



        }

        public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
        {




            switch (item.ItemId)
            {
                case Android.Resource.Id.Home:
                    mDrawerLayout.OpenDrawer((int)GravityFlags.Left);
                    return true;


                default:
                    return base.OnOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
        }

        private void SetUpDrawerContent(NavigationView navigationView)
        {
            navigationView.NavigationItemSelected += (object sender, NavigationView.NavigationItemSelectedEventArgs e) =>
            {
                int id = e.MenuItem.ItemId;

                switch (id)
                {

                    case Resource.Id.nav_home:
                        Intent home = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
                        this.StartActivity(home);
                        GC.Collect();

                        break;

                    case Resource.Id.nav_peacehero:

                        Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(PeaceFragement));
                        this.StartActivity(intent);
                        GC.Collect();

                        break;

                    //case Resource.Id.nav_discussion:

                    //    Intent discuss = new Intent(this, typeof(PeaceHeroActivity));
                    //    this.StartActivity(discuss);

                    //    break;

                    //case Resource.Id.nav_event:

                    //    Intent peace_event = new Intent(this, typeof(PeaceHeroActivity));
                    //    this.StartActivity(peace_event);


                    //    break;

                    //case Resource.Id.nav_donate:

                        //Intent donate = new Intent(this, typeof(PeaceHeroActivity));
                        //this.StartActivity(donate);

                        //break;
                }



                e.MenuItem.SetChecked(true);
                mDrawerLayout.CloseDrawers();
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `fragment3` which contains the `RecycleView` used in `SomeActivity`?

Comment: @apineda Yeah. In SomeActivity, I am trying to get the id of the RecycleView in fragment so i update it with the data that i am currently saving

Comment: What you are looking to do is not possible because the RecycleVIew it's not in the context of the Activity but in the context of the Fragment. The good news is that you don't need it. In your Fragment3 expose a public method where you pass in the data and in that method you can update your RecycleView adapter.

Comment: @apineda. Could you please let me understand your code.

Comment: Looking better at your code I see I had some missing pieces. Please update the original post with the complete code of the `Fragment3.cs ` and the `SomeActivity`

Comment: @apineda, It is updated now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146300/discussion-between-apineda-and-amateur).